# Nested collection created as array instead of collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I am having some trouble when I create a new model form json, with nested attributes that should be parsed as a collection. Here I show how I get to the error:

(Any help appreciated)

1) I create a user like this

```
user = new App.Models.User( {"email":"tom@gmail.com","id":1,"user_cities_attributes":[{"city_id":431,"user_action":"to-visit","user_id":1}] }
```

2) and then I check in the console what happened, the collection did not get created. :S

```
user.get('user_cities')
> undefined # where is my collection?! :(
user.get('user_cities_attributes')
> [Object] # mmm weird...
```

If I try after to add a new model to the collection...

```
cities = new App.Collections.CitiesCollection()
cities.fetch()

userCity = new App.Models.UserCity( { user: user, city: cities.first(), user_action: "to-visit" } )
```

now everything seems to be fine... what happened????

```
user.get('user_cities')
> Backbone.Collection {length: 20, models: Array[20], _byId: Object, model: function, user: User…}
user.get('user_cities_attributes')
undefined
```

MODELS

```
class App.Models.User extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  paramRoot: 'user'
  urlRoot: 'users'

  defaults:
    name: null

class App.Models.UserCity extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  paramRoot: 'user_city'
  urlRoot: 'user_cities'

  defaults:
    user_action: null

  relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasOne,
    key: 'user',
    relatedModel: 'App.Models.User',
    collectionType: 'App.Collections.UsersCollection',
    keySource: 'user_id',
    includeInJSON: 'id',
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'user_cities',
      keySource: 'user_cities_attributes',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
    }
  },
  {
    type: Backbone.HasOne,
    key: 'city',
    relatedModel: 'App.Models.City',
    collectionType: 'App.Collections.CitiesCollection',
    includeInJSON: 'id',
    keySource: 'city_id',
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'users',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
    } 
  }]

class App.Models.City extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  paramRoot: 'city'
  urlRoot: 'cities'

  defaults:
    name: null

  relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'places',
    relatedModel: 'App.Models.Place',
    collectionType: 'App.Collections.PlacesCollection',
    keySource: 'places_attributes',
    # parse: true,
    includeInJSON: 'id',
    autoFetch: true,
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'city',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
    }
      # 'relatedModel' is automatically set to 'Zoo'; the 'relationType' to 'HasOne'.
  }]
```

Comment: Look at the note about `reverseRelation` and using coffeescript: http://backbonerelational.org/#relations-reverseRelation. Then try using `.setup` as described here: http://backbonerelational.org/#RelationalModel-setup

Comment: That actually solved my problem :) Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the note about reverseRelation and using coffeescript (from: http://backbonerelational.org/#relations-reverseRelation):

> Note that if you define a relation (plus a reverseRelation) on a
>   model,    but don't actually create an instance of that model, it is
>   possible initializeRelations will never get   called, and the
>   reverseRelation will not be initialized. This can happen when extend
>   has been overridden, or redefined as in CoffeeScript. See setup.

Then try using .setup as described here: http://backbonerelational.org/#RelationalModel-setup